# Winter '14 Salesforce MVP Nominations are Open

Tags: discussion, mvp

Salesforce recently opened the Winter '14 MVP nominations.  See [Vote Now: Winter '14 Salesforce MVP Nominations are Open](http://blogs.salesforce.com/company/2013/12/winter-14-salesforce-mvp-nominations.html)

It would be great to get more StackExchange representation for those who put effort into running this community site (like our [moderators](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators)) and answering questions (see [users](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=year)).

Is it appropriate to encourage users to go and vote for those how have helped them?

I'm thinking probably not directly in the question comments, but it would be great if we could promote the MVP voting casually to visitors.

Answer (score 8):

Couldn't agree more.  Actually just nominated 2 users from here.  Love to get more MVPs on SFSE.